# Does MSBuild also link?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have used msbuild from commandline to build my sln projects. But I can't find the exe output anywhere.
Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Post the `msbuild` command line, and copy/paste the complete output from the console window.

Comment: Learn how to use MSBuild binlog, and then nothing is hidden from you any more, https://msbuildlog.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MSBuild command line to build your project, it can specify the `outputpath` of the project.

Use like this `-p:outputpath=C:\test`, `C:\test` is the new output folder of your project.

More msbuild command line arguments, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019).

So you should use like this:

```
msbuild xxx\xxx.sln -t:build -p:outputpath=xxx(specified new output path)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!